# Slackbot + Heroku: Have to keep logging in

Tags: heroku, slack, botkit

I'm having an issue with my botkit slack bot hosted on Heroku.  The bot itself is just the "starter kit."

https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-slack

After a little while, the bot stops working.  The logs complain of not being able to find the team.  I hit the /login path of my heroku-deployed app and allow it and it works again for a bit.

Is there a heroku configuration that I need to change to keep it from going idle or something?  Or is this an issue with the starter kit?  Could there be something I need to do in the slack configuration?

Comment: Are you connecting to any database with your bot? If so you have to make sure that you don't hit the connection limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you run your bot on a hobby dyno. Heroku sends hobby dynos to sleep if they dont receive any requests.

What had happened:

1. You deployed the bot -> the bot is running and working
2. Everybody can write with the bot -> so great!
3. After a few minutes, while the bot is not used, the dyno falls asleep
4. At this moment the bot is not working
5. You hit the /login request and yeah -> the dyno starts again and the bot is running and working

Read more about free dynos here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours.

**Solution: Switch to Standard Dynos**